# Docker plugin provides this option "Commit agent's Docker container" to commit the image of the agent.I want to configure this job using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have tried to configure this jon manually and it works fine, but not getting appropriate options/functions to achieve this. basically i'm trying to achieve s2I using jenkins with the help of plugin Docker.[Job screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvGjJ.png)